Gitlab CICD rule gets disregarded when passing a variable from the upstream to the downstream pipeline
I have a multi pipeline project setup, where the e2e project is defined as a trigger job in the client/server projects.
My goal is to not run the e2e stage on scheduled pipelines.
In my gitlab-ci.yml files of the server/client projects, I have defined a variable TRIGGERING_PIPELINE_SOURCE = $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE using Gitlab's predefined variables in order to be able to pass it down to the downstream pipeline.
I added the same variables in my e2e project to be able to identify the CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE of the triggering pipeline. I logged the variable in my e2e jobs, and verified it is indeed passed down correctly - the triggering pipeline source is schedule for scheduled runs.
With this in mind, I created a rule in my trigger projects:
rules:
 - if: $TRIGGERING_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
   when: never
 - ...other rules to run the pipeline when it's a merge request, on merge trains, and on master
 - when: manual 

And with this, the e2e project has an option to be run manually on scheduled runs, which falls in the when: manual rule.
So the first rule is completely disregarded, even though the variables are correct and are being passed correctly from the upstream to the downstream pipeline.
Is this a gitlab bug, or am I doing something wrong?

If you are passing the variable to another job, it should be something like
job1:
  stage: mystage
  script:
    - echo "FOO=BAR" > vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env
job2:
  stage: mystage
  needs: [job1]
  script:
    - echo '$FOO'"is ${FOO}"

As shown in the example, the variable starts with $. For comparing the variables in rules, it is the same and you need to add $:
rules:
 - if: $TRIGGERING_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
   when: never


yeah I used the $ sign, thanks for pointing it out - I will update my post. As I mentioned, I verified that the variable is passed down correctly from the logs in my downstream job, so that is not the issue.
